# Can't compile rTorrent with xmlrpc-c

Tags: rtorrent

I'm trying to setup xmlrpc-c with rTorrent but for some reason I failed:

```
checking for XMLRPC-C... failed
```

Here's my build script:

```
output_dir=/home/world/apps

curl -Lso - http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpc-c/files/Xmlrpc-c%20Super%20Stable/1.25.24/xmlrpc-c-1.25.24.tgz/download | tar xzf -
cd xmlrpc-c-1.25.24
./configure --prefix=$output_dir
make && make install
cd ..

curl -Lso - http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libsigc++/2.2/libsigc++-2.2.10.tar.bz2 | tar xjf -
cd libsigc++-2.2.10
./configure --prefix=$output_dir
make && make install

export sigc_CFLAGS=-I$output_dir/include
export sigc_LIBS=$output_dir/lib

curl -Lso - http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/downloads/libtorrent-0.13.3.tar.gz | tar xzf -
cd libtorrent-0.13.3
./configure --prefix=$output_dir
make && make install
cd ..

export libtorrent_CFLAGS=-I$output_dir/include
export libtorrent_LIBS=$output_dir/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$output_dir/bin

curl -Lso - http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/downloads/rtorrent-0.9.3.tar.gz | tar xzf -
cd rtorrent-0.9.3
./configure --with-xmlrpc-c=$output_dir/bin/xmlrpc-c-config --prefix=$output_dir
make && make install
```

How come it' fails to check for XMLRPC-C?

Comment: what's the output from the build script? it's not (directly) "checking for XMLRPC-C"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure XMLRPC is installed properly?

If its not, try giving entire URL for XMLRPC in the first line for curl. Could be a broken URL. I tried the link. It didn't work individually.

`curl -Lso - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xmlrpc-c/Xmlrpc-c%20Super%20Stable/1.25.24/xmlrpc-c-1.25.24.tgz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fxmlrpc-c%2Ffiles%2F&ts=1374217827&use_mirror=kaz`

Or rather try installing XMLRPC manually before going ahead with the others.

Comment: Yep, when I try `xmlrpc-c-config --help` it shows some usage help.